# Valid proof for $A \times ( B - C) = (A \times B) - (A \times C)$?

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Prove that for all sets $A,B,C$ $$A \times ( B - C) = (A \times B) - (A \times C).$$

My proof:

$$
\begin{align}
A \times (B-C) &= \{(a,b) \mid a \in A \land b \in B-C\} \\
&= \{(a,b) \mid a \in A \land b \in B \land b \notin C\}
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
(A\times B) - (A\times C) &= \{(a,b) \mid a \in A \land b \in B\} \cap \{(a,b) \mid a \in A \land b \in C\}^{c} \\
&= \{(a,b) \mid a \in A \land b \in B\} \cap \{(a,b) \mid a \notin A \lor b\notin C\} \\
&= \{(a,b) \mid (a \in A \land b \in B) \land (a \notin A \lor b\notin C)\} \\
&= \{(a,b) \mid b \in B \land [(a \in A \land a \notin A) \lor(a \in A \land b\notin C)]\} \\
&= \{(a,b) \mid b \in B \land a \in A \land b\notin C\} \\
&= \{(a,b) \mid a \in A \land b \in B \land b \notin C\} = A \times (B-C)
\end{align}
$$ I am especially wondering about the validity of combining the intersection via set builder notation

Comment: "about the validity of combining the union via set builder notation"  You mean the intersection?  i.e claming $\{x|P(x)\} \cap \{x|Q(x)\} = \{x| P(x) \land Q(x)\}$?  Sure.  That's utterly valid.

Comment: yes, I did mean intersection (mistype)

Comment: No, biggie.  Yes.  You can always do $M \cap N = \{x|x \in M\} \cap \{x| x \in N\} = \{x| x \in M \land x \in N\}$ is *perfectly* acceptable.  I'd even say it's desirable.

Comment: Likewis you can do $M\cup N = \{x|x \in M\}\cup \{x|x\in N\} = \{x|x \in M \lor x\in N\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct. However, it is simpler to do it as follows. Given $(x,y)$,\begin{align}(x,y)\in A\times(B\setminus C)&\iff x\in A\wedge y\in B\setminus C\\&\iff x\in A\wedge y\in B\wedge y\notin C\end{align}and\begin{align}(x,y)\in(A\times B)\setminus(A\times C)&\iff(x,y)\in A\times B\wedge(x,y)\notin A\times C\\&\iff x\in A\wedge y\in B\wedge(x\notin A\vee y\notin C)\\&\iff x\in A\wedge y\in B\wedge y\notin C.\end{align}It's the same idea, but I think that it is easier to read.